# Can any multithread issues occur when using biConsumer function in state on spring singleton class?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, singleton

I have five class that validate inputs null checks and business checks. Below one is one of them and We regrouped some dublicate codes via using biConsumer function that we never did before. But we are not quite sure that if multithread comes at the same time, how biConsumer function behaves? Because this is stateful class right now.

```
    @Component
public class AgencyPersonValidation implements IPersonValidation {

    private ValidationDefinitionService validationDefinitionService;

    @Autowired
    public AgencyPersonValidation(ValidationDefinitionService validationDefinitionService) {
        this.validationDefinitionService = validationDefinitionService;
    }

    private final BiConsumer<PersonRequest, MapBindingResult> checkNullObjectsConsumer = (personRequest, result) -> {
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullPersonnelInformation(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullPersonnelOrganizationInformation(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkPersonnelContactInformation(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkPersonnelSalesInformation(personRequest, result);
    };

    private final BiConsumer<PersonRequest, MapBindingResult> checkNullFieldsConsumer = (personRequest, result) -> {
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullPersonType(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullRequestSystem(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullCreateDate(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullUpdateDate(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullUpdateUserId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullCreateUserId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullName(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullSurname(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullMaidenName(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmail(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullBusinessLineId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullDepartmentId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullUnitRegionId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullPositionId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullTitleId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullAgencyId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullAgencyRegistrationNo(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullSuperriorPersonnelId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullIdentityNumber(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkDigitIdentityNumber(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullGender(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullMaritialStatus(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullBirthCountryId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullBirthCityId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullBirthDate(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullFatherName(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmploymentStatus(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmploymentStartDate(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmploymentEndDate(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullChangeStartDate(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkNullIsTechnicalPerson(personRequest, result);
    };

    private final BiConsumer<PersonRequest, MapBindingResult> checkBusinessControlsConsumer = (personRequest, result) -> {
        validationDefinitionService.checkTechnicalPersonnelNoIsEmpty(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkTechnicalExamIsEmpty(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkTechnicalPersonnelIsEmpty(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkOldEmployeeIdIsEmpty(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkYoungEntrepreneurGroupIdIsEmpty(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkAgencyPersonnel(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkSateliteIsConnectedToRegionForAgency(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkAgencyIsConnectedToRegion(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkAgencyTitle(personRequest, result);
    };

    private final BiConsumer<PersonRequest, MapBindingResult> checkDbRecordsConsumer = (personRequest, result) -> {
        validationDefinitionService.checkDepartmentIdIsExist(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkBusinessLineIdIsExist(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkUnitRegionIdIsExist(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkCreateUserIdExists(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkUpdateUserIdExists(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkPersonnelPositionIsExistsWithId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkPersonnelTitleIsExistsWithId(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkDepartmentCodeIsExistsInUnitRegion(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkSuperiorTrainingStatusIdIsExist(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkImposedProcessTypeIsExist(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkYoungEntrepreneurGroupIdDigitNo(personRequest, result);
    };

    private final BiConsumer<PersonRequest, MapBindingResult> checkBusinessControlsForUpdateConsumer = (personRequest, result) -> {
        validationDefinitionService.checkPersonIsSuitableForUpdate(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkQuitedPersonHasATeam(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkPersonDepartmentChanges(personRequest, result);
        validationDefinitionService.checkAlreadyExistsSateliteBranch(personRequest, result);
    };


    @Override
    public void doCreateValidation(PersonRequest personRequest, MapBindingResult result) {
        checkNullObjectsConsumer.accept(personRequest, result);
        checkNullFieldsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmployeeIdPrefix(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmployeeId(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullUsername(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullNationalityId(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullAccessIdList(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
        checkDbRecordsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkEmployeeIdExists(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkUsernameIsExist(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkSuperiorJobIdIsExist(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkExemptionTrainingStatusIdExist(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkTrainingsAreExist(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
        checkBusinessControlsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkPersonTypeCreate(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
    }


    @Override
    public void doUpdateValidation(PersonRequest personRequest, MapBindingResult result) {
        checkNullObjectsConsumer.accept(personRequest, result);
        checkNullFieldsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmployeeIdPrefix(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmployeeId(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullUsername(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullNationalityId(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullAccessIdList(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
        checkDbRecordsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.isPersonnelNotExist(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkPersonnelUserNotExists(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
        checkBusinessControlsConsumer.accept(personRequest, result);
        checkBusinessControlsForUpdateConsumer.accept(personRequest, result);
    }

    @Override
    public void doSmCreateValidation(PersonRequest personRequest, MapBindingResult result) {
        checkNullObjectsConsumer.accept(personRequest, result);
        checkNullFieldsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullProcessStatus(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullRequestId(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
        checkDbRecordsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkEmployeeIdExists(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
        checkBusinessControlsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkPersonTypeCreate(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
    }

    @Override
    public void doSmUpdateValidation(PersonRequest personRequest, MapBindingResult result) {

        checkNullObjectsConsumer.accept(personRequest, result);
        checkNullFieldsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullSMRecordId(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullEmployeeId(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullProcessStatus(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkNullRequestId(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
        checkDbRecordsConsumer
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkSMRecordIdIsExist(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.isPersonnelNotExist(per, res))
                .andThen((per, res) -> validationDefinitionService.checkPersonnelUserNotExists(per, res)).accept(personRequest,result);
        checkBusinessControlsConsumer.accept(personRequest, result);
        checkBusinessControlsForUpdateConsumer.accept(personRequest, result);
    }
}
```

ValidationDefinitionService which is autowired on agencyPersonValidation, is also singleton class but not stateful. Might we have any multithread issues from this code? Or biConsumer functions just do their job only for every thread?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Because this is stateful class right now"* In what way is that class stateful? As far as I can see, there is no fields maintaining state, and there is no actions that would change any kind of state. As such, without state, that class should be fully thread-safe. Well, unless `ValidationDefinitionService` has state (but you already said it doesn't) or isn't otherwise thread-safe.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for comment. there are consumer variables (biconsumers) in class scope?

Comment: So? That variable (field) refers to a method, to code, not to any state value fields. There is no state there. And those variables (fields) are all final, so they can never change once the class instance has been created. I don't understand what "state" you believe they have.

Comment: then these biconsumers not indicating any state. I was confused. thanks.

Comment: The `checkNullObjectsConsumer` field is no more stateful than the `validationDefinitionService` field. It is assigned on instance creation and never changes after that. "State" refers to classes where calling a method with the same arguments repeatedly might produce different results because the "state" of the class has been changed. That requires some kind of mutator method, e.g. a method like `set`, `add`, `remove`, etc. There are no such methods here.